# Glossaries package with recursive terms (eg TCP/IP)

Tags: glossaries, recursion

[TeXstudio on Mac]

I'm using the glossaries package, and I'm wondering how best to handle recursion?

For example, with the following glossary terms defined (note the `tcpip` definition invokes the other two recursively:

```
\newglossaryentry{tcp}{name=TCP, description={Transmission Control Protocol}}
\newglossaryentry{ip}{name=IP, description={Internet Protocol}}
\newglossaryentry{tcpip}{name=TCP/IP, description={Internet protocol suite comprising of both the \gls{tcp} and \gls{ip} protocols}}
```

I include the term *TCP/IP* in my document using the `\gls{tcpip}` command.  As a result of this command, the glossary now includes the entry:

```
TCP/IP Internet protocol suite comprising of both the TCP and IP protocols
```

However, in addition to the above entry, I was hoping that definitions for both *TCP* and *IP* would also now be included.

The glossary package is able to correctly substitute the nested `\gls` commands, but doesn't add the associated entries to the glossary.  Thus the reader, in my example, is left wondering what *TCP* and *IP* mean.

*Update after Nicola posted her answer*

My present build sequence (using TeXstudio on Mac) is:

```
txs:///compile | txs:///makeglossaries | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile| txs:///compile | txs:///makecopy | txs:///view
```

And I have one `\makeglossaries` in the preamble of my document, as you do in your example.

So, are you saying that I need to insert an additional `txs:///makeglossaries` into my build command after one of the succeeding compile invocations?

Comment: @TeXnician:  Where would I put those commands?  My understanding, so far (and I've just started using this package) is that terms appear in the glossary only when they are used in the text.

Comment: Your use of `\gls` in the description is the method I recommend, but you need an extra LaTeX+`makeglossaries` in your build process. See also [Nested Links](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Thanks, I'm already doing that.  @TeXnician, It worked when I used `\glsadd` in the definition of `tcpip`.  Funny thing was that I only needed to apply that function to one of the recursively defined terms, `tcp` in my case, and both *TCP* and *IP* have shown up in the glossary.  Cheers!

Comment: @TeXnician: Hmm, I spoke kind of too early.  I needed to two builds.  However each build already invokes `makeglossaries`.  So it appears that I need to run `makeglossaries` an equivalent number of times to the depth of the recursion?

Comment: @TeXnician:  The `\glsadd{ip}` command wasn't necessary.  The solution is, simply but unfortunately, to re-build as per my previous comment.

Comment: @gone That's what Nicola Talbot wrote (who is the author of the package, so she should know).

Comment: Right.  Well, she didn't explicitly mention running it numerous times, but I guess the *Nested Links* link would have informed me of the need.  Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Just an after thought... It would be nice if the package was able to handle this automatically, but maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: @gone It can be handled by `bib2gls` and `glossaries-extra`. I'll update my answer to include that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{tcp}{name=TCP, description={Transmission Control Protocol}}
\newglossaryentry{ip}{name=IP, description={Internet Protocol}}
\newglossaryentry{tcpip}{name=TCP/IP, description={Internet protocol suite 
comprising of both the \gls{tcp} and \gls{ip} protocols}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\gls{tcpip}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

On the first LaTeX run, `tcpip` is indexed on page 1. The glossary doesn't exists so the description isn't typeset, which means that the `\gls` instances in the description aren't processed. So, if the document is called `myDoc.tex`, if the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

then the PDF only shows TCP/IP in the glossary:

[image: Glossary TCP/IP Internet protocol suite comprising of both the TCP and IP protocols. 1]

but if you look in the `.glo` file you'll find that the TCP and IP entries have been indexed:

```
\glossaryentry{TCP/IP?\glossentry{tcpip}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{TCP?\glossentry{tcp}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}
\glossaryentry{IP?\glossentry{ip}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}
```

They were indexed on the second `pdflatex` when the glossary was being typeset. An extra `makeglossaries` and LaTeX call are required to update the glossary, so the complete build process requires:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

Now IP and TCP show in the glossary (with the page number 2, which is where they were indexed in the `tcpip` description).

[image: Glossary IP Internet Protocol. 2 TCP Transmission Control Protocol. 2 TCP/IP Internet protocol suite comprising of both the TCP and IP protocols. 1]

If the dependent terms also reference a term in their description then that term can't be indexed until the dependent terms have their descriptions typeset in the glossary. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{transmission}{name={transmission},
  description={programme or signal that is broadcast or sent out}}
\newglossaryentry{tcp}{name=TCP,
  description={\Gls{transmission} Control Protocol}}
\newglossaryentry{ip}{name=IP, description={Internet Protocol}}
\newglossaryentry{tcpip}{name=TCP/IP, description={Internet protocol suite 
comprising of both the \gls{tcp} and \gls{ip} protocols}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\gls{tcpip}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This now requires:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

If you want an automated method that follows through all the dependencies then you need to switch to `bib2gls` and `glossaries-extra`. This requires that the entries are defined in a `.bib` file. For example, `entries.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@entry{transmission,
  name={transmission},
  description = {programme or signal that is broadcast or sent out}
}

@entry{tcp,
  name = {TCP},
  description = {\Gls{transmission} Control Protocol}
}

@entry{ip,
  name = {IP},
  description = {Internet Protocol}
}

@entry{tcpip,
  name = {TCP/IP},
  description = {Internet protocol suite 
   comprising of both the \gls{tcp} and \gls{ip} protocols}
}
```

The document (`myDoc.tex`) now looks like:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
 postpunc=dot]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[% using bib2gls
  src = {entries}% terms defined in entries.bib
]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\gls{tcpip}.

\printunsrtglossaries % <-- 'unsrt' variant needed with bib2gls

\end{document}
```

The document build process is now:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

If you want a visible separation between letter groups, you need the `--group` (or `-g`) switch:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls -g myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

The glossary now includes all the dependent terms:

[image: Glossary IP Internet Protocol. TCP Transmission Control Protocol. TCP/IP Internet protocol suite comprising of both the TCP and IP protocols. 1 transmission programme or signal that is broadcast or sent out.]

but note the dependent terms don't include the page number. Those can only be obtained on a subsequent `bib2gls` + LaTeX call so the complete build process needs to be:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls -g myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls -g myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

but at least this limits the maximum number of calls required to ensure the locations are up to date.

[image: Glossary IP Internet Protocol. 2 TCP Transmission Control Protocol. 2 TCP/IP Internet protocol suite comprising of both the TCP and IP protocols. 1 transmission programme or signal that is broadcast or sent out. 2]

You may prefer to omit the page numbers for the entries that only appear in the document and only have page numbers for the entries that are explicitly indexed in the document. In this case, you can change the default format (encap) to `glsignore` at the start of the glossary:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
 postpunc=dot]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[% using bib2gls
  src = {entries}% terms defined in entries.bib
]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\gls{tcpip}.

\GlsXtrSetDefaultNumberFormat{glsignore}
\printunsrtglossaries % <-- 'unsrt' variant needed with bib2gls

\end{document}
```

Now the document is up-to-date with just the sequence:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls --group myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

(Naturally, if you need to add a bibliography etc, then the build process becomes more complicated.) You may also need an extra `bib2gls`+LaTeX after deleting all the temporary files since `\gls` just produces `??` on the first LaTeX call. This can only be resolved once `bib2gls` has created the file input by `\GlsXtrLoadResources` and this may cause a shift in the page breaks once `\gls` produces the correct text. (This doesn't affect the appear of the entries in the glossary, but may alter the location lists slightly.)

Comment: Thanks.  However I'm still a little confused as to where the additional `makeglossaries` should go.  I have extended my OP to include my current build settings and document construction.

Comment: @gone I think you'd need `txs:///compile | txs:///makeglossaries | txs:///compile | txs:///makeglossaries | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile| txs:///compile | txs:///makecopy | txs:///view` but with `bib2gls` you'd just need `txs:///compile | txs:///bib2gls | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile| txs:///compile | txs:///makecopy | txs:///view` (You'd need to configure TeXStudio to recognise `bib2gls`. I would imagine that you'd just need to follow the instructions for `makeglossaries` but replace `makeglossaries` with `bib2gls`, but I've never used TeXStudio.)

Comment: Cheers!  I'll stick with the `makeglossaries` approach for now as it satisfies my present need.  The additional information will come in handy if I have a more complicated piece of work to do.